# Flip view in iphone with navigation bar

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want to include Flip view in my project. I made it like this but cant work properly
 and secondary view contains an image veiw

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(flipView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButton;
UIBarButtonItem *returnButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"return"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(returnView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = returnButton;
```

and i set the action like this

```
- (void)flipView{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                           forView:[self view]
                             cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:secondaryView];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


- (void)returnView {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:[self view]
                             cache:YES];
    [secondaryView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly..?

Comment: You call self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButton; and then you call self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = returnButton; So, my understanding is that, you only have returnButton, that means -flipView never gets called.

Comment: @AdilSoomro flipbutton not visible return button is visible insted of flip.. every time it performs the return view action

Comment: @Canopus ya the same .... what to do to get the flip button at first and return buton after flipping..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

surely as you're putting the code, nothing happens because you're not giving the opportunity to do the flip.

try to MOVE these lines:

```
UIBarButtonItem *returnButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"return"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(returnView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = returnButton;
```

inside of flipView, after or before the animation. And copy these other lines:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flipButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Flip"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(flipView)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = flipButton;
```

inside of returnView. You'll see the change.

I hope to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Set `[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondaryView animated:YES];`

instead of `[self.view addSubview:secondaryView];` and write

```
forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
```

instead of `forView:[self view]`.
`